sdelete unexpected output for deleting a single file
I read the instructions. I read the blogs demonstrating it. I even watched a YouTube video of this. None present this output.
PS I:\misc> sdelete -p 7 .\my-secure-file.zip

SDelete v2.05 - Secure file delete
Copyright (C) 1999-2023 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

SDelete is set for 7 passes.
I:\misc\my-secure-file.zip...deleted.
No files/folders found that match .\my-secure-file.zip.
Zeroing free space to securely delete compressed files: 0%
Could not determine disk cluster size:
The system cannot find the path specified.

Zeroing free space to securely delete compressed files: 0%
Could not determine disk cluster size:
The system cannot find the path specified.

Zeroing free space to securely delete compressed files: 0%
Could not create free-space cleanup file:
Access is denied.

Zeroing free space to securely delete compressed files: 0%
Ctrl+c hit

It appears to do the job, then begins zero'ing free space which I wasn't expecting. At this point I panicked and hit control-c. No apparent harm done. What am I missing here?

What kind of disk is I:?

@grawity_u1686 HDD attached by USB
